# CoreOS: dockerized mongo instance connection refused from another dockeried mongo

Tags: mongodb, docker, coreos

I've set up two services on my CoreOS instance. Briefly, the first one is an official mongo container and the other one is a custom made image that's trying to connect to a "mongo" instance.

```
  - name: living-mongo.service
    command: start
    enable: true
    content: |-
      [Unit]
      Description=Mongo
      Author=Living
      After=docker.service

      [Service]
      Restart=always
      RestartSec=10s
      ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop mongo
      ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm mongo
      ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 --hostname mongo mongo:2.6
      ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop mongo
      ExecStopPost=-/usr/bin/docker rm mongo
  - name: living-mongo-seed.service
    command: start
    enable: true
    content: |-
      [Unit]
      Description=Mongo Seed
      Author=Living
      Requires=living-mongo.service
      After=living-mongo.service

      [Service]
      User=core
      Type=oneshot
      ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop mongo-seed
      ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm mongo-seed
      ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name mongo-seed --link mongo:mongo registry.living-digital-way.com/mongo-qa:v1
      ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop mongo-seed
```

Basiclly, first I start the mongo instance, and then I'm trying to connect to it to feed some data on there:

```
# docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 --hostname mongo mongo:2.6
# docker run --name mongo-seed --link mongo:mongo registry.living-digital-way.com/mongo-qa:v1
```

When the second service is started, it's telling me:

```
Sep 12 14:12:21 core-01 docker[1672]: Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.living-digital-way.com/mongo-qa:v1
Sep 12 14:12:21 core-01 docker[1672]: 2016-09-12T14:12:21.704+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 172.17.0.4:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
Sep 12 14:12:21 core-01 docker[1672]: couldn't connect to [mongo] couldn't connect to server mongo:27017 (172.17.0.4), connection attempt failed
Sep 12 14:12:21 core-01 docker[1672]: 2016-09-12T14:12:21.728+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 172.17.0.4:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
Sep 12 14:12:21 core-01 docker[1672]: couldn't connect to [mongo] couldn't connect to server mongo:27017 (172.17.0.4), connection attempt failed
```

Once the system is started, I manually perform the second service on shell:

```
docker run --name mongo-seed --link mongo:mongo registry.living-digital-way.com/mongo-qa:v1
```

and it works fine.

What am I doing worng?

**EDIT**

Custom docker image Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:2.6
MAINTAINER Living Digital Way
COPY ./clients.init.json .
COPY ./users.init.json .
COPY ./import.sh .

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./import.sh"] # -> only required, if import.sh is not executable
CMD ["./import.sh"]
```

and `import.sh`:

```
mongoimport --host mongo --db lvdb --collection clients --type json --file ./clients.init.json --jsonArray --upsert --upsertFields client_id
mongoimport --host mongo --db lvdb --collection users --type json --file ./users.init.json --jsonArray --upsert --upsertFields username
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out where the connection is being dropped.

Start with inspecting the mongo container to ensure the public IP is correct.

```
docker inspect mongo_container | egrep "IPAddress[^,]+"
```

This will print the IP address - ensure this is correct.

Stand up the Container as a daemon (if not already)

```
docker run -it -d mongo
```

Get container ID

```
docker ps -a
```

Log into container

```
docker exec -it mongo_container_id bash
```

Install curl

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get curl
```

Ping MongoDB Endpoint

```
curl localhost:27017
```

Should print out

```
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

control + d to exit the container.

Run the same commands while container is still up but instead of localhost use the IP from this command.

```
docker inspect mongo_container | egrep "IPAddress[^,]+"

curl 172.17.4.124:27017
```

Should see the same output

```
 It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

Either the IP, the port, the port exposure, the server, or the container is not up.

Comment: I've just tested everything you have written down. Everything appears as you has pointed. So, it seems everything works well. Take in mind, this containers are kicked off on boot stage.

Comment: Show us the code that the custom docker image uses to connect to the official mongo container. If you are not already hard code in the container IP address:mongodb_port

Comment: I've added in post the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: 1. If you are connecting to mongo:27017 change that to mondo container IP : port number so "containder_ip:mongo_port"


2. It's possible the mongo container is not up yet when you execute the connection, can you stand of the mondo container then wait a bit before attempting to connect? I believe that may be your issue.